# Using Adhoc or push notifications to transfer data between Ipad/Ipod/Computer

Tags: ipad, ipod, apple-push-notifications, adhoc

I have quite a few questions to ask about these issues. I'm an intern for a company that wants to use Ipads and Ipod touches along with a simulation. We want to connect around twenty Ipod touches with an Ipad. Students will answer a question on the iPod touch which that result should be sent to the Ipad(instructor) and then the instructor "pushes" the next question for the iTouches. Needless to say, I'm not sure where to even start to make this idea come true, I've been looking up AdHoc stuff and that seems like it's mainly for distribution as opposed to devices actually "talking" with one another. If anyone has any helpful tutorials, links, etc. that would be an amazing answer of how to start this project. Thank you!

So far I've found these links:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services
This mainly focuses on applications that aren't active at the time but still need to push data, correct? We don't need to worry about that, the student will only have that app up at the time.

http://www.macoscoders.com/2009/05/17/iphone-apple-push-notification-service-apns/
Also found this
http://www.knowing.net/index.php/monotouch-ad-hoc-distribution-tutorial/
Mainly about distribution again

Comment: I've been out of state for the majority of Winter Break. Can I just say if someone wanted to do any sort of this project, your answer could have helped them as well as myself. Just because someone doesn't respond quickly doesn't mean they're ignoring it on purpose. Thank you for taking the time to respond, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are thinking of is AdHoc distribution, which is a method of deploying an app to a limited number of devices (200) without going through the App Store.  But applications built using an AdHoc provisioning profile are tied to specific devices, and expire after a few months (it's mainly intended for testing).

Push notifications don't apply in this case.  They are used when you want to push some data from an Internet server to notify the user about an app that may not be running.

Provided your pile of iPod Touches and iPad have wi-fi access, GameKit would get you up and running quickly.  However, I believe an iPad is limited to 16 peers.

Comment: That would be a great option, we could probably shrink it to 16 peers if that is the case or add another iPad. (By the way, I wish it was my pile of iPod Touches haha) Thank you very much and I'll definitely be checking GameKit out!

Comment: @Joe Blow, I must have been thinking of the hosted match, which involves a separate server that is not an iPhone or iPad (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW30)